# Fourier series of $x^3$ from $x^2$

Tags: integration, derivatives, fourier-series

The Fourier series of $x^2$ is:

$$x^2 = \frac{4}{3} + 16\sum_{r=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^r}{\pi^2r^2} \cos(\frac{\pi r x}{2}) \\ 0 \le x \le 2$$

To find the Fourier series of $x^3$, we can integrate term by term to obtain:

$$\frac{x^3}{3} = \frac{4x}{3}+32\sum_{r=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^r}{\pi^3 r^3} \sin(\frac{\pi r x}{2}) + c$$

where c is the constant of integration.

However, I have noted from my textbook, that this is not the actual Fourier series and the $\frac{4x}{3}$ must written into a Fourier series by differentiating the series for $x^2$

Why is the differentiation required? Could we simply leave as it is? Would the deviation be great?

Comment: No, you cannot keep the linear part $4x/3.$ The only functions that can appear in Fourrier series are sine and cosine ... (and constants). They describe wawes, while linear function does not.

Comment: Sorry but I have to ask, I understand that the whole point of fourier series is to convert functions into harmonic functions. But what exactly is the reason why we can't keep the linear portions within the function?

Comment: Because it isn't a Fourier series.  A Fourier series (period $2\pi$) is defined as a series of the form $\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}} c_n e^{inx}$, $c_n\in\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: @user10354138 thank u sirs

Comment: The series is the one for $4x^2$ in $[-1,1]$.

Comment: Note that a fourier series describes one portion of an equation repeating over and over, so if you have a linear part in the equation no two of the parts (which should appear periodic) would be the same. That means that by definition it is not a fourier series

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No , you cannot leave $\frac{4x}{3}$ , as a Fourier series contains a constant and the terms containing sine and cosines. So you have to expand the linear part also.